# Ordering Posts by parent category, name ascending

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, query-posts, get-posts

I am currently creating a theme, and I have 2 parent categories: Budget and Brand.

On home.php, I want to order all the posts ascending by their sub category name without showing the category title. This is what i had:

```
query_posts(
    'post_type=post&posts_per_page=125&paged=' . get_query_var('paged') 
);
```

And this is what I'm trying:

```
query_posts( 
    array( 
        'category__and' => array(57 ), 
        'posts_per_page' => 125, 
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC' 
    ) 
);
```

However, I'm getting the white screen of death and nothing is showing up. The **57** is the parent category id of brands.

What is causing this not to work?

Comment: In wp-config.php set wp_debug to true `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`, it might give you clues why it's not working. Also you should really be using the WP_QUERY class https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: You should **never ever** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query and page functionalities, it is also slow and rerun queries.